# ComboBox direction control

Tags: expression-blend, silverlight-embedded

I want to see if i can set the direction that the combo boxes will pop up when the user clicks on them. I am developing this for WEC7 Platform Builder project with Silverlight for Embedded Application project.

My main issue is, i have some combo box elements towards the bottom of my screen due to content density on the screen. As a result, when i click on the combo box, it will first open facing up. However, when selecting it again, it will face down. This causes the combo box scroll bar to become so little that you cannot actually scroll and are forced to click the up and down arrow buttons.

Can i set the direction that the combo box will open?

Thanks,

Comment: I forget for embedded, but does the property `PlacementMode` exist? So you can just add like `<ComboBox Placementmode="Top".../>`

Comment: @ChrisW. Unfortunately, `PlacementMode` is not a property of the `ComboBox` that i have available.

Comment: I'd bet you could just tweak the style template and use a quick `BasedOn` for it, but I couldn't seem to find the default style templates in docs for embedded to see.